# Hide full name in cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment, desktop, appearance

Can I hide full name of desktop objects? Long names keep appearance ugly. Is there a config file or setting for do that? I use cinnamon in linux mint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Desktop` folder in the file manager and open the `.desktop` file corresponding to the "troubled" icon in a text editor of your choice.

Edit the `Name=…` line as you wish. :)

After saving, the corresponding desktop icon should now have the altered label.

Comment: I don't want to do that for all files and ... . Is there a way to auto hide full name of objects? For example: 26 GB Volume -> 26 GB Vo...